# VSTS - Recover the team project if deleted

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I recently setup VSTS in my organization, would like to know the process of recovering the team project if it deleted.

Whom should we need to contact immediately if it has happened?

I went through this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/team-services-security-whitepaper?view=vsts) which was not clear whom to contact, what to do. But we can get data 30 days old only.

Thanks

Comment: Personally I would never assume that syncing with a cloud service is adequate, because you can always sync corruption and accidental deletions as well as good stuff. I would review your local backup strategy to make sure you can always recover from that.

Comment: Each post is already associated with a profile, so signatures are not needed on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The deleted VSTS project can not be recovered. More details, you can refer [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/projects/delete-project?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#choose-to-delete-a-project):

> Caution
>
> Deleting a project permanently removes data associated with that
>   project from the database. You cannot recover it later. Therefore, you
>   should save project data that you might want to access later.